# WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse: Web services not published

Tags: web-services, websphere, ibm-wdt

I am using eclipse Mars, IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5 for developers, and using WAS 8.5 Developer Tools for Eclipse plugin.

When I right click my ear project in eclipse and choose to run my application the application is published and deployed on the server but web services are not published. I know in webspehere to publish my web services I must run endPtEnabler over my ear file before installation on the server to amend the ear file and add required websphere artifacts for web services.

As a work around for now,  I had to generate the ear and apply endPtEnabler in maven install cycle, and I wrote jython script to be used in eclipse run configuration to install/update the application, However, this is painful to do with every change since changes are not hot deployed and I had to install the ear and run the jython script.

Is there a way to configure eclipse plugin to publish web services directly when running the application through eclipse??

UPDATE 1:

Service Class:

```
package com.home.da.services.mq.simulators;
import static com.home.core.common.constants.ConstantValues.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.home.core.mq.xml.bind.bill.req.SendSystemNotificationRequest;
import com.home.da.services.mq.MQAccessorLocal;


@WebService(serviceName="ReceiveTransactionService",
            endpointInterface = "com.home.da.services.mq.simulators.ReceiveTransaction",
            portName = "ReceiveTransactionPort",
            targetNamespace = "http://home.com/BILL")
@Stateless
public class ReceiveTransactionWS implements ReceiveTransaction{

        @EJB
        private MQAccessorLocal mqAccessorLocal;

        @Override
        public void sendTransaction(SendSystemNotificationRequest trx) {
            mqAccessorLocal.sendMQMessage(Boolean.FALSE, trx, "com.home.core.mq.xml.bind.bill.req", null, JNDI_NOTF_BILL_SYS_REQ, null, null, null, "999999999");
        }

    }
```

SEI:

```
package com.home.da.services.mq.simulators;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import com.home.core.mq.xml.bind.bill.req.SendSystemNotificationRequest;

@WebService(name = "ReceiveTransaction", targetNamespace = "http://home.com/BILL")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED,
             use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
             style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface ReceiveTransaction {

    public void sendTransaction(SendSystemNotificationRequest trx);
}
```

File context:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXdtO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *[WebSphere Application Server classic] Create router modules* section of the IBM Knowledge Center [WebSphere Developer Tools for web services development topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/core/cwsinwsa.htm?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5&lang=en).  Additional detail on the Create Router Modules wizard (which was formerly known as the Endpoint Enabler) can be found at the [*Creating web service router modules* topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/core/tendenabl.htm?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5&lang=en) .

Comment: I followed the link but there is no "Create Router Modules" available on the ejb context menu. I updated the question for depiction.